# Reversing an on-demand iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, reverse-iterator

I have an iterator `DataIterator` that produces values on-demand, so the dereference operator returns a Data, and not a Data&.  I thought it was an OK thing to do, until I tried to reverse the data DataIterator by wrapping it in a reverse_iterator.

```
DataCollection collection

std::reverse_iterator<DataIterator> rBegin(iter) //iter is a DataIterator that's part-way through the collection
std::reverse_iterator<DataIterator> rEnd(collection.cbegin());

auto Found = std::find_if(
    rBegin, 
    rEnd,
    [](const Data& candidate){
        return candidate.Value() == 0x00;
});
```

When I run the above code, it never finds a Data object whose value is equal to 0, even though I know one exists.  When I stick a breakpoint inside the predicate, I see weird values that I would never expect to see like 0xCCCC - probably uninitialized memory.  What happens is that the reverse_iterator's dereference operator looks like this (from xutility - Visual Studio 2010)

```
Data& operator*() const
{   // return designated value
    DataIterator _Tmp = current;
    return (*--_Tmp); //Here's the problem - the * operator on DataIterator returns a value instead of a reference
}
```

The last line is where the problem is - a temporary Data gets created and reference to that data gets returned.  The reference is invalid immediately.

If I change my predicate in std::find_if to take (Data candidate) instead of (const Data& candidate) then the predicate works - but I'm pretty sure I'm just getting lucky with undefined behavior there. The reference is invalid, but I'm making a copy of the data before the memory gets clobbered.

**What can I do?**

1. Fix my DataIterator so that operator* returns a Data& instead of a Data?  I don't really see how this is possible.  The whole point of my DataIterator returning a Data instead of a Data& is because I don't have room to hold the entire uncompressed data set in memory, so I create the items that you want to look at on demand.  <s>Maybe I could hold onto the 'current' data value - but then that reference is going to become invalid the moment you increment or decrement the DataIterator.</s>  **Edit** [one of the answers suggests a shared_ptr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21104251/1508243)
2. Write a specialization of the reverse_iterator and make its dereference operator return a value instead of a reference?  This seems like a frustrating amount of work, but understandable since it's my DataIterator that's not playing nice here - not the rest of the STL.
3. Along the same lines, maybe make a find_if that goes in reverse - probably less work than specializing reverse_iterator.
4. Something else I haven't thought of

Is there something I can do to DataIterator that will prevent someone else from blowing half a day figuring out what's wrong when they try the same thing 6 months from now?

Comment: Why did you choose an iterator for this task?

Comment: copy datas to `vector<Data>`, and use `reverse_iterator` on that vector

Comment: An iterator was chosen because the underlying data is very very large, but compressed.  The iterator decompresses the data, one item at a time as you iterate over it.  That lets us look at the data set, and lazily create derived datasets without having to keep multiple very large data sets alive in memory.

Comment: `std::reverse_iterator` requires its parameter to be a Bidirectional iterator (C++11§[reverse.iter.requirements]/1). Your iterator is at best an Input iterator since even the lowly Forward iterator requires `operator*` to evaluate to a `value_type&` ([forward.iterators]/1). You will have to write your own specialization of `reverse_iterator`.

Comment: @Casey - it's frustrating.  It's almost a random access iterator, and I want it to be treated that way so I can do things like binary search it, but you're basically right.  I don't know what's less work - calling it a random access iterator and patching up problems like this one, or calling it a forward iterator and patching up search algorithms and other similar things

Comment: @PeteBaughman It's unquestionably one of the worst design flaws in the standard library, right up there with coupling I/O, formatting, nationalization, and character coding together in iostreams. The Boost folks did a bunch of work separating the concepts of traversal and access in iterators a while back ([New Iterator Concepts](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/iterator/doc/new-iter-concepts.html)), there were even some proposal papers for the language committee, but I don't think anything ever came of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with Casey's suggestion in the comments.  He didn't post it as an answer that I can accept, so I'll write it up myself.

I made a specialization of the reverse_iterator for DataIterator that returns a value instead of a reference.  This involved copy/pasting the implementation from xutility, specifying one of the template arguments to be a DataIterator, and changing

```
reference operator*() const
```

to

```
value operator*() const
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm a great fan of the idea, but if you heap allocated a `Data` object and then returned a ref to a `shared_ptr` to it, that would allow the outside world to hold onto it longer if needed, and for you to "forget" about it when you step forward.

On the other hand, implementing your own native `reverse_iterator` might be a bigger win.  That's what I did for my own linked list since I didn't use a sentinel object like `gcc` does and couldn't use `std::reverse_iterator`. It really wasn't that difficult.

Comment: Does a reference to a shared_ptr keep it alive?  Regardless - If I were starting again, then some type of reference counting would probably be the way to go.  Unfortunately I think it's too big of a change to the existing code-base right now.

Comment: A reference to a `shared_ptr` won't keep it alive by itself, but if someone wants to use it, they'll probably copy it into another `shared_ptr`.  That will keep it alive.

Comment: Got it - the step I was missing in my head was caching the shared_ptr in a private field of the iterator.  The private field gets cleared out when you move the iterator, and if anybody else grabbed a copy in the meantime the underlying data stays alive

Comment: @woolstar When returning a `shared_ptr` you should always return it by value, not as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `reverse_iterator` interface was designed before the existence of `decltype`.  Today, that would be written as

```
auto operator*() const -> decltype(*current)
{   // return designated value
    DataIterator _Tmp = current;
    return (*--_Tmp);
}
```

and [in C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html), even the trailing return type won't be needed, since it can be inferred.

```
decltype(auto) operator*() const
{   // return designated value
    DataIterator _Tmp = current;
    return (*--_Tmp);
}
```

Comment: My goodness.. That C++14 code looks pretty neat. However, I'm not sure I'd be comfortable with that. I mean, I think it's too much like var in C# and javascript and what not. There's just something about seeing the type that I like. It is convenient though and the first time I'm seeing this. +1 from me.